# How to pass a CustomEvent as an argument and dispatch it?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, arguments

How can I pass a CustomEvent as an argument to a class and later dispatch it? An example of what I would like to achieve is below  - **non working**

```
var container:Container = new Container(array, new ViewEvent(ViewEvent.PHOTO_SELECTED));
addChild(container);
```

and in container:

```
public class Container extends Sprite

public function Container(array:Array, e:ViewEvent):void
{
     _objectsArray = array;
     _event = e;
     addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
}
```

---

```
private function selected():void
{
    dispatchEvent(new ViewEvent(_event, true, false, _selectedID));
}
```

So when `selected()` is called the View event that is passed into the constructor is fired.

Comment: Can you please clarify? You're asking how to achieve something yet posting the code......... achieve what exactly?

Comment: This seems to be partial code. Can you post the code that calls the selected() function, or is there even one?

Comment: hey how does an `Event` dispatch another event? It is itself dispatched by some one na? I cant figure out how an Event Object will throw an `ADDED_TO_STAGE` event

Comment: sorry guys sleep is needed. Simple problem - answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised it wasnt an `Event` I needed to pass, but rather the string value.

```
var container:Container = new Container(array, ViewEvent.PHOTO_SELECTED);
```

-

```
public function Container(array:Array, e:String):void
{
 _objectsArray = array;
 _event = e;
 addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
}
```

---

```
private function selected():void
{
dispatchEvent(new ViewEvent(_event, true, false, _selectedID));
}
```